# redirect page during day of week AND during specific time

Tags: javascript, html

I can redirect on specific day of week and starting at a specific time, but I don't know how to make a second time to END redirecting.  Here is the script that I'm using.  n==3 specifies Wednesday, and then time==19 specifies 7pm.  But what I'm trying to figure out is how to make it so it only redirects during a specific time period on wednesday.  For example only redirect between 7pm and 9pm on wednesdays.

```
function myFunction() {
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getDay()
   var time=.getHours()
   if(n==3)
   {
   //based on time
   if(time==19)
   {
    window.location.href="www.YourRedirectpage.com";
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
function myFunction() {
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getDay()
   var time=.getHours()
   if(n==3)
   {
   //based on time
   if(time >= 19 && time <= 21)
   {
    window.location.href="www.YourRedirectpage.com";
   }

 }
```

This will redirect if time is between 19(7) and 21(9).